# How to delete my CV on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Because of a mistake the last time I logged in to Stack Overflow, I clicked on CV, but I had no intention to create a CV. I just like to help others to solve issues and am not interested in a job. Now I see an empty CV that I would to delete. Stack Overflow, I think, did not foresee this eventuality... How do I delete my CV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly you can't, and need to email them? I'm not sure — this seems to suggest you'll have to email.

[How do you delete your CV from the new Careers site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24999/how-do-you-delete-your-cv-from-the-new-careers-site) <sub>10k to see, as it's deleted</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I just emailed my request to support site for asking to delete my CV. Thanks.

Comment: Would setting the CV to "to block all messages and searches" be enough? I was only looking and now there's a CV. Some people could lose their job because of such a mistake in their profile. :-(

Comment: @stesch I would email the folks in the link above and ask for the CV to be removed -- I don't know enough about how that section works to answer definitively, I'm afraid.

Comment: My request accepted by support team, my CV was deleted. Thanks!

Comment: This is old, but the only relevant answer for "how to delete my CV." Link in answer is 404. Can someone please explain how to delete CV? Thank you.

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo You're right, it's definitely a 404 now. I skimmed the Jobs area briefly under my own profile, and it looked like the only option was to just delete my profile (not what I want to do, I'm sure not what you want to do, either). Can you try emailing careers@stackoverflow.com and asking?

Comment: @MichaelArmes No reply from careers. However, I found option after login to make developer story private. My CV is gone.

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo oh good -- I'm sorry you didn't get a response, but I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. Thank you for updating with what worked for you!

Answer (score 5):

SO Response:

> It is not possible to delete the CV itself - the only thing you can do is delete all the information that is contained within it (each individual entry has an option to delete it from your story). Alternatively, you can mark the entire thing as private so only you can view any of the information.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove your resume or CV from Stack Overflow easily (in Oct 2020). Here are the steps:

1. Click on your profile.
2. Click on "Edit Profile and Settings"
3. Under the section "PERSONAL INFORMATION", click on "Job preferences".
4. Scroll to the bottom section "Resume", and click on the "Remove" button.
5. Click on the "SAVE" button at the bottom of the page.

IMPORTANT: If you forget to click on the "SAVE" button in step (5), your resume may not be removed at all.